# VMware Player does not detect Wacom tablet

Tags: vmware-player

I got a WACOM STU500 which is working fine under Windows 10 without installation of any drivers. If the tablet can be found, can be tested with the tool available under http://gsdt.wacom.eu/support/STU-Utilities.xml

Now I want to make use the tablet under a Windows 7 VM, but the tablet is not found by VMware Player 12.5.8. When I go to "Player -> Removeable devices, the tablet is not shown here...

According to this information, theres no driver needed for Win 7:
http://gsdt.wacom.eu/download/Wacom-STU-Tablet-Driver.xml

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation from VMware](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-07883F0A-E7B5-4CBA-837D-0BA986E8B900.html) (this particular page is for VMware Workstation 9, but it should be generally applicable) says:

> By default, USB HIDs, such as USB 1.1 and 2.0 mouse and keyboard devices, do not appear in the Removable Devices menu in a virtual machine, even though they are plugged in to USB ports on the host system.

The Wacom tablet likely falls into this category.  As instructed by the documentation:

1. Power off the VM.
2. Open the settings for the VM.
3. Select the USB controller, check "Show all USB input devices.", click OK.
4. Power on the VM.